# compare documents within single collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The below collection named "IgnitionData" is maintained in the mongodb. Here I am showing only relevant members of document.

```
data: {[   
    {"_id":1, "ignition": 0,"date" : ISODate("2014-03-01T09:00:00Z")},
    {"_id":2, "ignition": 1,"date" : ISODate("2014-03-01T09:01:00Z")},
    {"_id":3, "ignition": 1,"date" : ISODate("2014-03-01T09:02:00Z")},
    {"_id":4, "ignition": 1,"date" : ISODate("2014-04-01T09:03:00Z")},
    {"_id":5, "ignition": 1,"date" : ISODate("2014-04-01T09:04:00Z")},
    {"_id":6, "ignition": 0,"date" : ISODate("2014-04-01T09:05:00Z")},
    {"_id":7, "ignition": 1,"date" : ISODate("2014-03-01T09:06:00Z")},
    {"_id":8, "ignition": 1,"date" : ISODate("2014-03-01T09:07:00Z")},
    {"_id":9, "ignition": 1,"date" : ISODate("2014-03-01T09:08:00Z")},
    {"_id":10, "ignition": 1,"date" : ISODate("2014-04-01T09:09:00Z")},
    {"_id":11, "ignition": 1,"date" : ISODate("2014-04-01T09:10:00Z")},
    {"_id":12, "ignition": 0,"date" : ISODate("2014-04-01T09:11:00Z")}
   }]
```

Now I need to generate a report where I need to show only Ignition ON duration. My output should look something like below

```
{
    {"_id":1, "StartTime": ISODate("2014-03-01T09:01:00Z"), "StopTime": ISODate("2014-03-01T09:04:00Z"), "totalDurationInMin" : 3},
    {"_id":2, "StartTime": ISODate("2014-03-01T09:06:00Z"), "StopTime": ISODate("2014-03-01T09:10:00Z"), "totalDurationInMin" : 4}
}
```

I can get the data on any list variable and run a loop. Check the transition of Ignition status ( 0 to 1 & 1 to 0) and calculate the total time but if its possible by using mongodb query operators that will be very helpful. This is going to lot of documents sometime so using variable would be costly operations.

**Possible Approch**

```
var mapFunction = function(){ for( var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++){
                                if ((this.data[i].ignition == "0") && (this.data[i+1].ignition == "1"))
                                {emit({StartDate: this.data[i].date});}
                                if ((this.data[i].ignition == "1" ) && (this.data[i+1].ignition == "0"))
                                {emit({EndDate: this.data[i].date});}           
                            }};


 var reduceFunction = function(key, values) { return values[1] - values[0]};

db.runCommand(
               {
                 mapReduce: ignitionData,
                 map: mapFunction,
                 reduce: reduceFunction,
                 out: { merge: stoppageTime }
               }
             )
```

Still I am not getting right answer. Someone please help.

Comment: Hi ManasP and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can I ask you a question about your data structure? It looks like the ignition data sub-documents would be suited to an [array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/), but you have them contained within a parent document. Is that deliberate?

Comment: Sorry Vince, its mistake, those would be individual documents. or even if I have as sub-document I'll use $unwind and make it individually.

Comment: OK, thanks. Can you [edit] the question to remove those opening and closing brackets, to make it clear?

Comment: Hi Vince, its done now

Comment: Hi @VinceBowdren .. any updates on my request?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try mongodb aggregation on the collection.
First sort the collection according to id and date and then apply grouping logic. Something similar to this:

```js
db.IgnitionData.aggregate(
   [
     { $sort: { ignition: 1, date: 1 } },
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "$_id",
           StartTime: { $first: "$date" },
           StopTime: { $last: "$date" }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

Comment: I try your answer but its not giving desired answer.

I need query which can detect the transition from 0 ->1 and than 1 -> 0. I want to capture that events.
and then deduct the timing between these two events.